# Correct procedure of giving Arghya to Surya according to our scriptures?

Tags: worship, surya

What is the correct procedure of giving Arghya to Surya/Sun God according to our scriptures? Arghya is a form of worship where water sometimes with different ingredients are offered to the Sun.

I happen to know a few pundits and astrologers, but they all suggest a different method. I would like to know what is written in our scriptures about this subject.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92956/discussion-on-question-by-shanayan-correct-procedure-of-giving-arghya-to-surya-a).